# Rails: Move close button on Bootstrap alert messages

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have added the flash messages feature to my rails app.

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
 <% unless key.to_s == 'timedout' %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
      <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert" class="close">×</a>
      <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li>
          <%= value %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 <% end %>
 <% end %>

.alert-alert
  margin-top: 10px
  background-color: #ffffff
  border-color: #ffffff
  color: #b94a48
  text-align: center


.alert-success
   margin-top: 10px
   color: #317EAC
   background-color: #f5f5f5
   border-color: #f5f5f5
   text-align: center


.alert-notice
  top: -10px
  color: #317EAC
  background-color: #ffffff
  border-color: #ffffff
  text-align: center

.alert
  height: 100%
  width: 100%
  line-height: 14px

.close
  height: 100%
  line-height: 14px
```

Everything works just fine as you can see in the below image:

[image]

Now I would like to move the close button right next to the text. Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li>
    <%= value %> <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes I have, but the close button still appears on the right, just like the image I have uploaded.

Comment: Remove the `close` class or tweak it via CSS. This is only for styling. I've updated the answer.